# How to import multiple images for a single SKU

Tags: magento2, import-products

According to [M2 Docs](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html):

> If importing multiple images for a single sku, insert a blank row below the sku, and enter the additional image file names in the appropriate columns. The additional rows are understood to belong to the parent sku.

But, when I try to do this I get an error:

[image]

This is my import:

[image]

The import appears to be treating my "additional rows" as different products and failing validation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To add additional images simply add them into the field `additional_images` with comma `(,)` separation you don't need to add an additional row for it

Answer (score 3):

Okay, it appears that you don't add a new row for each additional image you want to add. Instead, you add an extra column called `additional_images`. And insert the following:

`image02.jpg,image03.jpg`

Comment: @Jai the dude responding here is the original author, he's explaining how he did it and fixed his own problem

Comment: oh...my mistake. You can accept it as your answer. I am reverting review.